# Importing all the functions from a module fails after changing to wildcard import

Tags: python, import

The name of my file is `FunctionsAZ.py`. I am trying to import all the functions. In the past I would do

```
from FunctionsAZ import (name of functions separated by comma)
```

There are a lot of functions. I tried

```
from FunctionsAZ import *
```

I am getting this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FunctionsAZ'

What am I doing wrong? This feels like a really obvious thing. I am using Python 3.8.8 and Spyder 4.2.5 through Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your project structure.

Assuming your structure looks like this:

```
└── project
        ├── packaged_functions
        │   ├──────── FunctionsAZ.py
        │   └──────── FunctionsXY.py
```

In this case, your import statement should look like:

```
from packaged_functions.FunctionsXY import *
```

This is called ***asbsolute import***.

---

**EXTRAS:**

You can also use ***relative imports***  :

```
from ..FunctionsXY import *
```

Relative imports make use of dot notation to specify location.

- A single dot means that the module or package referenced is in the same directory as the current location.
- Two dots mean that it is in the parent directory of the current location—that is, the directory above.
- Three dots mean that it is in the grandparent directory, and so on.

This will probably be familiar to you if you use a Unix-like operating system.

Comment: But why did it work before?

Comment: I guess OP has made some changes to the file structure...

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just do:

```
import FunctionsAZ as faz

#calling the function
faz.nameoffunction()
```

This assumes that the module is in the same directory.
That is at least how I would do it

EDIT: At least considering that you want to import ALL the functions anyways and there isn't some other huge stuff in the file than those functions

Cheers